# Add multiple Checkboxes in ITextsharp html to pdf

Tags: c#, itext

I'm using the iTextSharp library to convert my html to pdf. The issue is I'm trying to add checkbox appearance using the below code:

```cs
string HTML,public static String FONT = "c:/windows/fonts/WINGDING.TTF";
 
public static String TEXT = "o";
        
public void HTMLToPdf( string FileName)
{
    string HTML="<!DOCTYPE html>
                 <html>
                   <head><title></title><meta charset='UTF-8'></head>
                   <body><div class='mystyle'>Here i want to print many checkbox lik appearances</div></body>
                 <html>";
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30f, 30f, 10f, 10f);
    pdfDoc.Add(p);
    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    Font f = new Font(bf, 12);
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph(TEXT, f);
    pdfDoc.Add(p);
}
```

The problem is this method adds the checkbox at the begining of pdf, please help me to attach the paragraph containing the checkbox value to my html.
Simply put, I'm getting the value at pdfDoc.Add(p), but I want it in a variable to print it many times in html.

Comment: Hi, have you tried iText 7?

Answer (score 2):

In fact, it is not very clear what was meant in the question:

> please help me to attach the paragraph containing the checkbox value to my html

I can assume that you wanted to convert HTML to PDF, and add paragraphs on the next line.
In general, it's a bad idea to use iTextSharp for this, since this library is outdated and no longer supported. I can suggest my own way of solving your problem in pdfHTML, this is an iText7 add-on. My code is in Java, but it's not much different from sharp.The main idea is not to close the document after html conversion. Because if you try to write a paragraph in a closed document, it will be at the very beginning, as in your example.

```
 String FONT = "c:/windows/fonts/WINGDING.TTF";
    String TEXT = "o";
    File htmlSource = new File("checkBoxHtml.html");
    File pdfDest = new File("output.pdf");

    ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();

    Document document = HtmlConverter.convertToDocument(new FileInputStream(htmlSource),
            new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(pdfDest)), converterProperties);
    PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FONT);
    Text text = new Text(TEXT);
    text.setFont(font);
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();

    // Adding text to the paragraph
    paragraph.add(text);

    // Adding paragraph to the document
    document.add(paragraph);
    document.close();
```